# Failing to read from two socket using Selector java

Tags: java, nio, serversocket

I have a snap of code like bellow:

Bytebuffer buffer1= ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
  Bytebuffer buffer2= ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

while(true)
  {

```
selector.select();
System.out.println("Ready Selector: "+num);
Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
Iterator it = selectedKeys.iterator();


while(it.hasNext())
   {

   SelectionKey key= (SelectionKey) it.next();

   if(key.isReadable())
    {

      if(key.attachment.toString("Socket1")
         {
            //read data and store in buffer 1
            SocketChannel channel1= (SocketChannel) key.channel();
             while (true) {

             int number_of_bytes=channel1.read(buffer1);                             
                          if (number_of_bytes <= 0) {
                              System.out.println("Number of bytes: "+number_of_bytes);
                              if(number_of_bytes==-1)
                              {
                                  key.cancel();
                                  channel1.close();
                              }
                            break;
                          } 

         }
     else if(key.attachment.toString("Socket2")
         {
            //read data and store in buffer 2
```

SocketChannel channel2= (SocketChannel) key.channel();

```
             while (true) {

             int number_of_bytes=channel1.read(buffer2);                             
                          if (number_of_bytes <= 0) {
                              System.out.println("Number of bytes: "+number_of_bytes);
                              if(number_of_bytes==-1)
                              {
                                  key.cancel();
                                  channel2.close();
                              }
                            break;
                          } 

         }
       }
}
```

Now the problem what i am facing is, I am getting data from only one socket. Like I have first open socket1 and entered some data. That data i can read in above code but socket2 data is not read. Again if i run socket2 at first and then socket1, i can read socket2 data but can not read socke1 data. Please help me to find out the bug in code..

Comment: Try to remove key from it before you processing the SelectionKey

Comment: You've omitted the part where "Socket1" or "Socket2" gets stored as the key attachment, and also the part that actually does the read. Please post the relevant code. NB using strings as key attachments is pretty arcane. The key itself contains the channel it is for, so you don't need the `String` or the if/else test. The key attachment is generally used for a `ByteBuffer` or a session context object.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say what your problem is without seeing more of the code, but your select loop should look like this:

```
while(it.hasNext())
{
    SelectionKey key= (SelectionKey) it.next();
    it.remove();
    if (!key.isValid())
        continue;
    if(key.isReadable())
    {
        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
        // read the channel
    }
}
```

You don't need the `String` attachment at all; you need to check each key for validity; and you need to remove each key from the selected keyset as you process it.

If your code still doesn't work like this you have a problem elsewhere, or else nobody is sending to the second connection.

**EDIT:** Re your edit, you must exit the read loop if you read zero bytes; otherwise you are just spinning mindlessly while there is nothing to do, and starving the other channels. You don't need to cancel the key: closing the channel does that

Comment: I am doing exactly same and it is not about any particular second connection. Let say, we have connection A and B. Now if i recieve data for A at first, data from B is not sotred, and also vice-versa. Again, I need the attatchment because I am sotring incoming data in two different buffer. So to find out which socket will store data at where, I need use attachment. But anyway this does not solved my problem.

Comment: (1) You aren't doing 'exactly the same'. (2) As per my comment, you need the attachment to *be* the buffer, or an object that contains it. (3) You still haven't posted the code that sets the attachment as requested.

Comment: I need to interchange data between socket 1 and socket 2. So if i do not add the string and add buffer as attachment, i will not be able to differentiate the sockets later point of time. And again the problem is in reading, not in attachment logic. So, please give solution for that.

Comment: @user2392631 That's not so. You can add an attachment that contains all the data the key needs to process the read event, for example the session's own input and output buffers, the alternate channel to write to, etc.